# android: service is not stopped properly?

Tags: android, service, camera, task

Currently im writing a camera app which should take pictures in a regular time intervall. For this my activity creates a IntentService, which starts a TimerTask with the desired delay. First time I start my app everything works fine. The pictures are taken in an regular time intervall of 10 seconds. But if i pause and resume my application the pictures are taken more frequently.

Here is my activity:

```
    public class AndroidCameraExample extends Activity implements PictureTakenListener {

      private static String CLASSTAG = "Android Surveillance Camera";
      private Button captureButton;
      private Context context;
      private LinearLayout layoutForPreview;

      private SurveillanceCamera camera;

      // for calling the background service
      private Intent backgroundServiceIntent = null;

      // will send a notification if time has lapsed and we should
      // take a new picture
      private SurveillanceBroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        context = this;

        layoutForPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        camera = new SurveillanceCamera(this, layoutForPreview);
        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(PictureCaptureListener);
        camera.addPictureTakenListener(this);

        startSurveillance();
      }

      private void startSurveillance() {
        Settings.surveillanceIsActive = true;
        camera.start();
        startBackroundService();
        registerBroadcastReceiver();
      }

      private void stopSurveillance() {
        Settings.surveillanceIsActive = false;
        if (receiver != null) {
          unregisterReceiver(receiver);
          receiver = null;
        }
        if (backgroundServiceIntent != null) {
          stopService(backgroundServiceIntent);
          backgroundServiceIntent = null;
        }
        camera.stop();
      }

      private void startBackroundService() {

        if (isServiceRunning(SurveillanceBackgroundService.class)) {
          Log.d(Settings.APPTAG, "The Service is already running");
        }

        if (backgroundServiceIntent == null) {
          backgroundServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SurveillanceBackgroundService.class);
          startService(backgroundServiceIntent);
        }

      }

      private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
          if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
        if (receiver == null) {
          IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SurveillanceBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
          filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
          receiver = new SurveillanceBroadcastReceiver();
          registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
      }

      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startSurveillance();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopSurveillance();
      }


  class SurveillanceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      camera.takePicture();
    }
  }
```

My Service

```
public class SurveillanceBackgroundService extends IntentService {

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        notifyTimeLapsed();
      }
    }, 100, Settings.timeIntervall * 1000);

  }

  private void notifyTimeLapsed() {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(SurveillanceBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
  }
}
```

I aleady checked that the service isn't running (in background) while the app is paused and started again afterwards, so I don't see any reason why the pictureTaking Event should be triggered more ofter after resuming.

I also use a small wrapper class for camera handling but i don't think this causes the problem. if you need to code for suggesting any solutions i will post it here anyway.

Any hints or help for this`?

EDIT: I overwrite onDestroy and onStart to Cancel the Timer and start it again but the problem stays the same. After resume more pictures are taken than before.

UPDATE: If I remove the method onStart the timer seems to get canceled directly and isn't started again? I added some Logger output in the methods and get this information:

05-15 18:56:03.478: I/com.test.androidcameraexample(10061): SurveillanceBackgroundService onHandleIntent

05-15 18:56:03.498: I/com.test.androidcameraexample(10061): SurveillanceBackgroundService onDestroy

```
 @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (t == null) {
      t = new Timer();
      t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          notifyTimeLapsed();
        }
      }, 100, Settings.timeIntervall * 1000);

    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    if (t == null) {
      t = new Timer();
      t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          notifyTimeLapsed();
        }
      }, 100, Settings.timeIntervall * 1000);
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();    
    t.cancel();
    t = null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was this:

> You need to call either [Timer.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel--) or [TimerTask.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--)
>   on the `Timer` or `TimerTask` that the service created, or else the
>   timer task will keep running in a background thread.

And then I added this:

> To get this to work reliably, you could specify one `Intent` action
>   for starting the timer, and another action for stopping the timer.

But, **there is actually a big (and subtle) problem** with storing a `Timer` variable in an `IntentService`. An `IntentService` creates its own background thread, and it quickly kills itself (after `onHandleIntent ()` returns) if there are no intents in its queue -- which would also mean your `Timer` value would be lost. So, even if you have 2 intent actions (for starting and stopping the timer), there is no way to guarantee that the stop action would have access to the original `Timer` value (since it could very well be creating a brand new `IntentService` instance)!

So, I recommend that you use the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule periodic alarms. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for some training on how to do that.

Comment: sadly it didn't helped to solve my problem. please see my edit above.

Comment: `onStart()` is deprecated, and your implementation is not adding anything anyway. `onDestroy()` may not always be called, and it is also up to Android when it actually kills a service, even if you tell it to stop the service.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using an intentService because i want to run it in the background later (even if my app is paused). my aim is to restart the app by using the service every two minutes, take a picture and allow android to go back to sleep afterwards. So,... well I dont want to do this timer stuff in my activity. But can you maybe provide an example how I can use a second intent to kill my task in the service?

Comment: Actually, I see a subtle problem. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: First: many thanks for your suggestions and help till now. i'm not sure. But this just came to my mind. Why not use the straight forward solution and just use a sleep-loop in the service onHandleIntent method? Would there be any side-affects or possible problems in don't see yet?

Comment: The reason i hasitate to use an AlarmManager is that i read a statement some time ago - I can't remember where - that an AlarmManager should not be used for very frequent events, but for events that occur maybe every hour or once a day. I'm also not sure if this is true or what is the exact reason for this "rule" (maybe this causes too much overhead?).

Comment: 1. If you sleep in a loop in `onHandleIntent()`, that method will never return, and therefore you will never be able to handle any subsequent intent with a "stop" action -- it would just stay forever in the IntentService's intent queue. 2. Yes, the AlarmManager has some overhead, so you have to weigh the pros and cons. You could also write a `Service` (that is not an IntentService), but that might be overkill.